Weighted hierarchical cumulative sum
I don't know if I'm using the correct terminology, but I'm trying to find the cumulative sum of each node in a tree structure, but the children node only contribute a percentage of its cumulative sum to its parent node's cumulative sum.
Emission(E1) = Emission(E1)
Emission(E2) = Emission(E2) + percent_Contribution(E1) * Emission(E1)
Emissions(E3) = Emission(E3) + percent_Contribution(E2) * Emission(E2)
This a sample of the result I want to achieve:



entityId
parentId
emission
percentContribution
cumulativeSum




E1
E2
10
80
10


E2
E3
20
80
20 + (10 * 80 / 100) = 28


E3
NULL
30
NULL
30 + (28 * 80 / 100) = 52.4



Note that this is a sample of the result I'm trying to achieve, as my actual table can have many more levels of hierarchy.
I'm unfamiliar with SQL, but my research tells me that I should right a recursive CTE, but I haven't been able to get it to work with the weighted value. If it's impossible to do with pure SQL, I would also appreciated being point toward the right direction.
Edited Table in case of parent having multiple child records:



entityId
parentId
emission
percentContribution
cumulativeSum




E1
E2
10
80
10


E4
E2
20
60
20


E2
E3
20
80
20 + (10 * 80 / 100) + (20 * 60 / 100)= 40


E3
NULL
30
NULL
30 + (40 * 80 / 100) = 62




Your data seems sorted backwards for how you wish to calculate. Start with E3 and loop backwards to E2 then E1.

@Bart McEndree Yes, my bad. I've updated to be more in line with how I wish to actually calculate it.

Do you need to show the math part "30 + (28 * 80 / 100) =" in the results for the CumulativeSum column?

Please add another record to your example to clarify the behaviour you want when a parent has multiple child records.

I've added another record to clarify the behavior I want went a parent has multiple children entities

That is a bit more difficult. Here is a cheat that kinda returns your expected results https://dbfiddle.uk/bNaRJDV4

Solution with new sorting
WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS (
  SELECT entityId, parentId, emission, percentContribution,  CAST(emission as DECIMAL(3,1)) as cumulativeSum
  FROM Emissions WHERE entityId='E1'  
  UNION ALL
  SELECT e.entityId, e.parentId, e.emission, e.percentContribution,  e.emission + (c.cumulativeSum * c.percentContribution /100) 
  FROM cte c
  INNER JOIN Emissions e ON e.entityId=c.parentId
  WHERE c.parentId is not null
)
SELECT * FROM cte ORDER BY entityId;

fiddle



entityId
parentId
emission
percentContribution
cumulativeSum




E1
E2
10
80
10.0


E2
E3
20
80
28.0


E3
NULL
30
null
52.4




Solution with original sorting (before OP edit). Recursion starts with E3 and works backwards to E1.
WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS (
  SELECT entityId, parentId, emission, percentContribution,  CAST(emission as DECIMAL(3,1)) as cumulativeSum
  FROM Emissions WHERE entityId='E3'  
  UNION ALL
  SELECT e.entityId, e.parentId, e.emission, e.percentContribution,  e.emission + (c.cumulativeSum * c.percentContribution /100) 
  FROM cte c
  INNER JOIN Emissions e ON e.entityId=c.parentId
  WHERE c.parentId is not null
)
SELECT * FROM cte ORDER BY entityId;

fiddle



entityId
parentId
emission
percentContribution
cumulativeSum




E1
null
30
null
52.4


E2
E1
20
80
28.0


E3
E2
10
80
10.0



